# ServiceRuntimeException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I got ServiceRuntimeException was unhandled by user code in the following code where ServiceRuntimeException is a self defined exception, how to resolve it?

```
List<Action> a=new List<Action>();
            try
            {
            foreach (var parallelActivity in parallelActivities)
            {
                a.Add(delegate
                          {
                              try
                              {
                                  parallelActivity.Execute();
                              }catch(ServiceRuntimeException e)
                              {
                                  throw e;//<--Exception thrown at this line
                              }
                          });
            }

                Parallel.Invoke(a.ToArray());
            }
            catch (ServiceRuntimeException e)
            {
                throw e;
            }catch(AggregateException e)
            {
                throw e.InnerExceptions[0];
            }
```

The definition of ServiceRuntimeException

```
public sealed class ServiceRuntimeException : Exception
    {
        public ServiceRuntimeException(string msg)
            : base(msg)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not throw an exception again by variable name after you caught it. You will lose the stack trace! If you caught something and want to re-throw it, use throw; without the variable. Or don't catch it in the first place.

Comment: @nvoigt, thanks for the advice of using throw, learning new thing. But that does not solve the problem here...

Answer (score 0):

> How to resolve it?

Handle it in user code. Your exception is thrown. You need to catch it somewhere. If you don't, it will end up in the unhandled exception handler, who will by default terminate your program.

Comment: I have catched it somewhere, but when the exception is thrown within Parallel.Invoke(...) it seems to ignore those catch outside the Parallel.Invoke

Comment: Your "handling" it is again throwing it. Make sure you catch it somewhere and handle it for good. The exceptions inside the Parallel.Invoke will indeed be caught as a single Aggregate Exception.

Answer (score 0):

instead of re throwing the exception `throw e;` i suggest you log the exception of write it to the screen so you can trace it and see why is it happening.

if you want to "handle" it, just don't throw the exception at the catch